# Show that $G=HN$ for $H$ subgroup and $N$ normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I have a practice problem that states following:

Lad $G$ be a group and let N be a normal subgroup in $G$ with index $p$ which is a prime.

Let $H$ be a subgroup in $G$ which is not contained in $N$. Show that $G=HN$.

My answer:

I have for $x \in HN$ then clearly $x \in G$ and therefore $HN \subseteq G$

However for $x \in G$ I have $gNg^{-1} \in N$ and $gHg^{-1} \notin N$

But how do I continue from here to show $G=HN$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $N\unlhd G$ and $H\le G$ it follows that $HN\le G$. Then:

\begin{alignat}{1}
p &= [G:N] \\
&= [G:HN][HN:N] \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}

From the assumption $H\nsubseteq N$ it follows that $N\lneq HN$ (proper subgroup) or, equivalently, $[HN:N]\gneq 1$. Therefore, by $(1)$, we get $[G:HN]=1$, *i.e.* $G=HN$.

Comment: Very nicely explained, thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** (For the case $G$ is finite.) What can be the order of the subgroup generated by $N\cup\{x\}$ where $x\in H\setminus N$?

(More generally.) Consider the quotient map $G\to G/N\cong\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

First, since $N$ is a normal subgroup, we can conclude that $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$. Next, let $x \in {H - N}$. Then, we know that $x \in H \implies x \in HN$ but $x \not \in N$. Thus, $N < HN \leqslant G$. By Lagrange's theorem, the index of $HN$ in $G$ is a proper divisor of the index of $N$ in $G$, which is a prime $p$. Since the only proper divisor of a prime is $1$, the index of $HN$ in $G$ is $1$, and hence, $HN = G$.

Comment: Is it true only for finite G? I can see the equation by $\frac{G}{N}=\frac{HN}{N} \frac{G}{HN}$ only when the orders written are finite.

Comment: Can you explain why index of $HN$ in $G$ is not p? p is also a divisor in p

Comment: Because if that is the case, then $HN=N$, since they have the same index. However, this is not possible since $N$ is a proper (strict) subgroup of $HN$.